# Comparing String with Integer in javascript

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, string-comparison

While working in my JS code today, I found the following situation and can not explain myself what should be the correct output ?

```
'sachin' > 2 // False

'sachin' < 2 // False

'sachin' == 2 // False
```

I expect result of either of `<` or `>` should be true. What am I missing ?

Comment: Does that comparison really make sense to you at all

Comment: @adeneo I know it does not make sense in code but I want to understand what browser will do when it encounters such a statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the runtime attempts to convert `'sachin'` to a number, it will fail and end up as `NaN`.  That special constant results in `false` for any comparison to any other numeric value. The `NaN` constant ("Not A Number") is not equal to any other value, nor is it less than or greater than any other value.

*edit* — the `==`, `<`, and `>` operators all "prefer" numbers to strings. If one operand is a number and the other a string, they'll always try to interpret the string as a number. It doesn't matter what order the operands appear in; what matters is the operand types.

(Strictly speaking, the results of `<` and `>` when `NaN` is involved are supposed to be `undefined`, according to the spec, but Firefox seems to give `false` instead.)

Comment: Does that mean runtime tries to convert left operator to the type of right hand operator ?

Comment: @blunderboy no, it has to do with the types of values involved, and the particular operator. I'll extend the answer (once I double-check the language spec to make sure my memory's OK :)

Comment: @blunderboy OK sorry I updated the answer - what I had written about `==` was incorrect; I think I was thinking about the `+` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!! I will go and read some article on type conversion in JS to make things more clear to me..